# Comparing columns of matrix and giving boolean output

Tags: matlab

I have checked other questions. I didn't find my answer. I have a matrix of n * 2 size. I want to compare the 1st and 2nd column and based on which is greater I want to assign 0/1 to the respective index. Suppose  I want an output as

```
a = 1 2
    4 3
    7 8
```

I want the output like this

```
out = 0 1
      1 0
      0 1
```

I did this :

```
o1 = a(:,1) > a (:,2)
o2 = not(o1)
out = [o1, o2]
```

This does the job but I am sure there's a better way to do this. Need suggestions on that/.
Forgot to mention, the datatype is float in the matrix.

Comment: Not sure why you want a better answer, that looks pretty good to me. Is there any particular problem you have?

Comment: I think your answer is good. Maybe reduce one line as: `o1 = a(:,1) > a (:,2)
out = [o1, ~o1] `... just for the sake of it... I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: @ David : No I didn't have any problems. Was just trying to reduce lines.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar : That does eliminate a line. Thank you.

Comment: haha... then make it one liner: `out = [a(:,1) > a (:,2), ~(a(:,1) > a (:,2))]`. On a serious note, will this increase computation. I mean will the expression - `a(:,1) > a (:,2)` - get computed twice?
@David what do you think?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar I did a few quick tests and OP's original solution was quicker and simpler than anything I came up with. The one-liner you gave there with two comparisons is actually slightly faster than creating the array and then doing `[o1 ~o1]` though.

Comment: @David aha... that's slightly surprising. I thought the one liner would compute `a(:,1) > a (:,2)`, thus increasing the computation time.

Comment: Actually it's dependent on the size of the matrix. The one-liner is better for very large matrices, where memory becomes a problem, the two-liner is faster for smaller problems. The differences are very small in all cases though.

Comment: If you enjoy comparing all the ways, you can consider also this one- `out=[(sign(a(:,1)-a(:,2))+1)/2, (sign(a(:,2)-a(:,1))+1)/2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more generic solution that can handle matrices with more than two columns:

```
out = bsxfun(@eq, a, max(a,[],2));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did is good. The number of lines doesn't really matter, what matters is the complexity of the operation in each line. Following the comments, I think you could gain some time as well by avoiding copy and multiple allocations:

```
out = false(size(a)); out(:,1) = (a(:,1) > a(:,2)); out(:,2) = ~out(:,1);
```

It is good practice to preallocate in Matlab, and in general to avoid copies in any programming language.
Optimizing further the runtime of this by using different operations is pointless IMO. If you really need speed you could Mex it to spare one iteration through the rows (second assignment), it's literally a dozen C lines, although you'd have to be careful about how you write the loop (the naive way would cause cache-miss at each iteration).

Comment: Using a logical matrix makes this so much more efficient than any other solution posted, good job!